# Socialite WP plugin, unable to obtain API keys from FB

Tags: plugins, facebook, api

I've installed the Socialite plugin for my wordpress blog, this allows your posts to be included in your facebook status as you publish them.

I'm trying to configure the plugin, it gives you a URL to visit in order to get your API key from facebook, but the URL it sends me to always gives an error (I've tried for several days now)

This question is really borderline facebook/Wordpress, but I'm wondering if anyone else has got this plugin successfully working with facebook, or if the URL that the plugin directs you to is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Socialite before today, so I did a quick install to see if I could reproduce the problem and ... wow ...

The system is *definitely* broken.

Facebook requires you to partially host your application on your own server.  You set up some integration so you can use its API, but most of the work actually happens off-site.  With other WordPress-Facebook integrations, you blog itself becomes the application ... Socialite seems to be hooking in to a system hosted by the plug-in developers as well.  This causes a significant problem because your site then becomes dependent on an external system to function properly - an external system that appears to be malfunctioning at the moment.  Also note that the last update to the system was made in December 2009 and the plug-in might not even be compatible with WP 3+.

The issue I see:

- *The URL the plug-in sends you to is correct.*  Every application must ask your permission to do things with your account, and it gets at least *that* far.
- *The callback URL seems to be broken.*  After authorizing an application, you're supposed to be sent to a specific callback URL (my guess is this will be the page that provides the "one time code" you enter into the plug-in configuration).

So for now, write Socialite off as "broken" and try another system.  I recommend [WPBook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpbook/) - it allows you to turn your blog into an application on Facebook, add it as a tab to your profile, add it as a tab to a fan page, and integrate comments between the two systems.

Comment: Thanks EAMann. WPBook sounds good, but I'm looking for a plugin that when I post a new post on my blog, it whacks it in my facebook status for publicity, thats all I need, any suggestions? (could open a new question on this)

Comment: I'd recommend opening a new question ... but one option would be the Facebook [NetworkedBlogs](http://apps.facebook.com/blognetworks/) application.  You tell it your blog URL, it automatically parses your feed, posts updates on your wall (and your friends' walls), and allows people to "follow" you directly within Facebook.  You can even post a widget on your blog to display your followers and tell your visitors how they can connect via Facebook (see [mine](http://mindsharestrategy.com) for an example).

Comment: Great answer. I just wanted to add that Facebook has a history of changing their API without regard to maintaining backward compatibility.

Comment: Yes they do.  If you want to stay up-to-date with expected changes in the API, keep an eye on the [Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).  Profile tabs, the bread-and-butter of many integration apps, will be gone as of Nov 3rd of this year ... things change quickly and without warning, so do everything you can to stay ahead of the curve.

Comment: *@EAMann* - Great effort on this one!